# Convert rows from a SQL Query or Table to JSON format

Tags: sql, json

I need a query result to be assigned to a column in the query response. I'm using 'For JSON' but I'm getting a strange error

This is the sub query I'm using and I want to convert the response to JSON

```
   {Account}.[Name],
        {Country}.[ISOCode], --Country ISO CODE
        {Account}.[BusinessTypeId], --AccountTypeID

        -- BusinessUnits
        (SELECT {BusinessUnit}.[Id] AS BusinessUnitId,
                {BusinessUnit}.[Name] AS BusinessUnitName
        FROM {BusinessUnit}
        INNER JOIN {BusinessUnit_Account} ON {BusinessUnit_Account}.[BusinessUnitId] = {BusinessUnit}.[Id]
        WHERE {BusinessUnit_Account}.[AccountId] = {Account}.[Id]
        FOR JSON PATH
        ) AS BusinessUnitUnits,

        {FarmDetail}.[FarmType_Id], --FarmTypeID
        {Account}.[Website],
```

I don't know why but the answer keeps fields that are not interesting or bring too much information.

Response:

```
500197  10SXo-G6226jywTlZlXf1   460115      Mariana Teste   FJ  65088   {"Business":[{"BusinessUnitId":2,"BusinessUnitName":"Swine"},{"BusinessUnitId":1,"BusinessUnitName":"Poultry"}]}    0   ssgsgsg sgsgsg  sgsgsg  sgsgsg  sgfsgsg 0   0   14
```

[image]

**NOTE:** I notice that the other fields are from another attributes of the table. But I only want to bring the attributes of the subquery

What am I doing wrong to not see the information that is underlined in red?

I've tried other options without success.

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it -- just take out the other stuff that isn't between the `(` and `)`  -- this part `FOR JSON PATH` is the part that makes the JSON -- other stuff won't.